# Global.TotalPages and Global.PageNumber always to 1

Tags: visual-studio-2012, report, rdlc, dynamics-nav, navision

In a rdlc report i want to add a textbox with "Page X/Y".

I use :

```
"Page "  & Global!PageNumber & "/" & Global!TotalPages
```

It's ok for all my report , but on a report, i don't know why, but i always have

```
Page 1/1
```

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot,

Best regards

Comment: I don't know if this is my problem, but I can't understand your question.

Comment: Hello Walter, this problem is various in NAV2009, NAV2013 and NAV2013R2. Which Version are you currently using? If i know that, i will post my solution. Greets

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure there is more than 1 page in that particular report. Otherwise, this error might occur.

The syntax seems correct. Check at the time you print the report the filters are all ok.

Answer (score 0):

The Global parameters are dependent on how you run the report and there is a big difference in the appearance, whether you are running it in Preview or in Print mode (you can change the mode in the top of the report when you are in Preview).

This is because reports are generated differently in the Preview and Print mode. In Preview mode the report is generated as the items are being fetched from the server and ignoring the boundaries of the actual page size and the Global parameters will not update accordingly. In Print mode the report is being generated page by page thus requiring that the page boundaries are always met.

Therefore should you try and test the report in Print mode and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Change Global!PageNumber to &PageNumber